# How to get values from three different tables in SQL Server with primary key and without?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables in SQL Server 2008 like this:

Table 1 with these columns:

```
[pod] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, primarykey
[origin] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[destination] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[town] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

Table 2 with these columns:

```
[town_id] [int] NOT NULL, primary key
[town] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

Table 3 with these columns:

```
[Area_id] [int] NOT NULL, primary key 
[town_id] [int] NOT NULL, foreign key of table 2
[area] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

With these details I want to get the values of

```
POD, origin, destination, town, area
```

My code:

```
SELECT 
    b.pod, b.origin, b.destination, b.town,
    af.area,
    (SELECT 
        *, 
        (SELECT a.area, a.town_id 
         FROM table3 a, town_table t 
         WHERE a.town_id = t.town_id) af 
     FROM table1 c, table2 tt 
     WHERE af.town_id = tt.town_id) 
FROM table1 b
```

I am not getting any idea please try to help me....

Thank you,....

Comment: for the start, put townId in table 1 after that should be straight forward.

Comment: SELECT b.pod,b.origin,b.destination,b.town,af.area
 I tried as follows MR Ajay Punekar   (SELECT *,
     (SELECT a.area,a.town_id
      FROM table3 a, town_table t WHERE a.town_id=t.town_id) af
   FROM table1 c, table2  tt WHERE af.town_id=tt.town_id)
 FROM table1 b

Comment: do your tables have foreign keys...please use them and use joins

Comment: On a side note, don't use tags that aren't relevant, such as in this case c# or asp.net. The problem you are asking people to solve has no mention or relevance to these 2 tags.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want, but at a guess it sounds like you want to get the 4 columns from table 1 and the 'area' column from the 3rd table using the 2nd table as a way of joining the 2. If that's the case this should work:

```
SELECT tb1.pod, tb1.origin, tb1.destination, tb1.town, tb3.area
FROM Table1 as tb1
JOIN Table2 as tb2
ON tb1.town = tb2.town
JOIN Table3 as tb3
ON tb3.town_id = tb2.town_id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below query :**

```
select POD, origin, destination , table1.town , area from Table1
inner join table2 on table2.town=table1.town
inner join Table3 on table2.town_id=table3.town_id
```

Answer (score 0):

select t1.pod,t1.origin,t1.destination,t1.town,t3.area from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.town=t2.town join table3 t3 on t2.town_id=t3.town_id

But as the comments say I also question the table design. A join over a varchar[50] field should be avoided. And all Fields that are used for the join should at least be indexed (in this example t1.town,t2.town,t2.town_id,t3.town_id)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT Table1.pod
, Table1.origin
, Table1.destination
, Table1.town
, Table3.area
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2
on Table1.town = Table2.town 
INNER JOIN Table3
on Table2.town_id = Table3.town_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    t1.pod,
    t1.origin,
    t1.destination,
    t1.town,
    t3.area
from
    table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t1.town = t2.town
    left join table3 t3 on t2.town_id = t3.town_id
```

Having a FK to town would be better on table 1 if possible

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.pod, a.origin, a.destination, a.town, c.area 
FROM (Table_1 a left join Table_2 b on a.town = b.town) left join Table_3 c on b.town_id = c.town_id
```

You lookup with the first join the town_id and with the second what area is connected to the town id.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
select a.POD, a.origin, a.destination ,a.town,c.area from Table1 as a,
inner join table2 as b on a.town=b.town
inner join Table3 as c on b.town_id=c.town_id
```